# Find all values of $x$ such that $\frac{x-4}{2x-3}$ is an integer.

Tags: fractions, integers

Find all values of $x$ such that $\frac{x-4}{2x-3}$ is an integer.

I tried many ways to do it, like by setting it to a fraction and what not, but it could just come for me, I hope you can help. Thanks a lot Math stack exchange. Thanks!

Still looking for an Anwser.

Comment: Do you mean $\frac{x-4}{2x-3}$?

Comment: yea thats what i mean.

Comment: Does $x$ have to be an integer as well, or can it be anything?

Comment: the question dosent state about x bieng an integer.. but it says find values for x that  (x-4)/2x-3  equals an integer

Comment: Are you sure $x$ is not an integer? If $x$ is a real number the question is kind of trivial as you are merely rearranging formulae, in which case stipulating that the rational function must be an integer is rather superfluous from a problem setting perspective.

Comment: Im not sure, the only thing the question states is find values for x that (x-4)/2x-3 equals an integer

Comment: It's a poorly written question then!

Comment: @LTS dont blame me, blame my teacher...

Comment: You can't really hide behing your teacher's back here. You posted it here after all.  But, yeah, the question isn't very interesting unless it's about integers. Another way to determine that would be, if you gave, krhm, **CONTEXT**. If you were studying divisibility in class, when this question came up, that would make it highly likely that $x$ is also supposed to be an integer. Your failure to provide such context caused ADG to answer the wrong question (if the constraint was there). Sad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I.e. solve in integers $2x-3\mid x-4$. Since $2x-3$ is odd, this is equivalent to $2x-3\mid 2(x-4)=2x-8$, which is equivalent to $2x-3\mid (2x-8)-(2x-3)=-5$, which is equivalent to $2x-3\in\{-5,-1,1,5\}$.

Comment: confused, first how did  2x−3∣x−42x−3∣x−4.  equal to 2x−3∣2(x−4)=2x−8  and second what is the anwser?

Comment: @AmanuelBogale The symbol "$\mid$" denotes "divides". So i.e. $2x-3\mid x-4$ means "$2x-3$ divides $x-4$", or i.e. "$x-4$ is divisible by $2x-3$".

Comment: if you didnt know sir, im a 10th grader, and dont know about the E stuff. I would like if it becomes easier..

Comment: @AmanuelBogale $\in$ denotes "belongs to". So i.e. $n\in\Bbb Z$ means "$n$ belongs to the set $\Bbb Z$", or i.e. "$n$ is a member of the set $\Bbb Z$".

Comment: Beautiful explanation!

Comment: first how did 2x−3∣x−42x−3∣x−4. equal to 2x−3∣2(x−4)=2x−8

Comment: I still need heLP!

Comment: @AmanuelBogale I.e. "$2x-3$ divides $x-4$" if and only if "$2x-3$ divides $2(x-4)$".

Comment: @user236182 OO so you equal the both equation and get anwser???

Comment: @user236182 nope dosent work :(

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac{x-4}{2x-3}=n\in\mathbb Z\implies x-4=2nx-3n\implies x=\frac{4-3n}{1-2n},n\in\mathbb Z$$

Comment: I am pretty sure $x \in \mathbb{Z}$, not $x \in \mathbb{R}$

Comment: @AmanuelBogale $\in\Bbb Z$ simply means "is an integer". Nothing more, nothing less. If I say, "$n\in\Bbb Z$", then I'm just saying "$n$ is an integer".

Comment: @AmanuelBogale You find all the values of $x$ by substituting $n=0,1,-1,2,-2 \ldots$

Comment: @user236182 x=1,2/3,8/5,11/9,7/3 give 3,2,-12,5,-1 five answers...

Comment: @Universe plug n=...,-2,-1,0,1,2,... in (4-3n)/(1-2n) to get values of coreesponding x.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31943/discussion-on-answer-by-adg-find-all-values-of-x-such-that-fracx-42x-3).